# www is not displayed in Google Search result

Tags: google-search, search-results

I have a website at `www.matrimonyteam.com`; when I perform a Google search it is only displaying `matrimonyteam.com` in search results rather than `www.matrimonyteam.com`.

Is there is any setting required at the time of hosting or in a config file to force the full domain name, with the `www`, to appear in search results?

Comment: who do you host with? You can usually specify it there. Personally, I think www is unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

I did a google search and your site is showing up both ways. If you have a webmaster account with Google you can specify it there. In other words you can tell google to display your search results whichever way you prefer. I agree with JohnP, though. The standard today is to not even bother with www. This really has nothing to do with the way your site is hosted. This is more of a function with DNS and how google is displaying your site.

Comment: tried to specify in google web master gives this king of alert Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own http://matrimonyteam.com/. Please verify http://matrimonyteam.com/.

Comment: Yashwant, you need to follow the instructions from google for verifying your site. It involves either modifying your home page with a meta tag or uploading a file. This is required by google so they can verify that you actually own the site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whether or not `www` appears in Google Search results is **irrelevant** to your visitors. They simply don't care. You might - but they don't
2. Ensure that whatever you choose, that your `no-www` redirects to `www` or vice-versa (using 301 redirect - normally done in *.htaccess* on Apache)
3. Google's Webmaster Tools has their [own help with verification](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35163) on the `www` vs. `no-www` situation

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single webpage that is accessible from 2 or more different URLS, then the canonical tag was invented for just that problem. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html